# Magento 2: How to create multiple custom shipping methods in a single module?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, module-development

I am referring this (https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-shipping-method/#step-1-declare-a-shipping-module) to create a custom shipping method. But I need to create multiple shipping methods. My doubt is that can we create multiple shipping methods in single module or we have to create separate modules for each.

Can anyone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple shipping methods in a single Module.

Here is an example **(config.xml)**:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Store/etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <chronopostcustommethod>
                <active>0</active>
                <title>DPD</title>
                <name>DPD</name>
                <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
                <sort_order>15</sort_order>
                <model>vendor\module\Model\Carrier\ChronopostCustomMethod</model>
            </chronopostcustommethod>
            <tntcustommethod>
                <active>1</active>
                <title>TNT</title>
                <name>TNT</name>
                <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
                <sort_order>16</sort_order>
                <model>vendor\module\Model\Carrier\TNTCustomMethod</model>
            </tntcustommethod>            
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to define two shipping methods in etc/adminhtml/system.xml file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="carriers" sortOrder="1000" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" showInDefault="1" translate="label">
            <group id="customship1" sortOrder="10" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" showInDefault="1" translate="label">
                <label>customship1</label>
                <field id="active" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" showInDefault="1" translate="label">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="name" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" showInDefault="1" translate="label">
                    <label>Shipp method1</label>
                </field>
                <field id="price" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" showInDefault="1" translate="label">
                    <label>Price</label>
                    <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                </field>
                ....
                ....
            </group>
            <group id="customship2" sortOrder="10" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" showInDefault="1" translate="label">
                <label>customship2</label>
                <field id="active" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" showInDefault="1" translate="label">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="name" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" showInDefault="1" translate="label">
                    <label>Method Name</label>
                </field>
                <field id="price" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" showInDefault="1" translate="label">
                    <label>Price</label>
                    <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                </field>
                ....
                ....

                
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Also create etc/config.xml file for save default settings

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <customship1>
                <model>Yourvendor\Yourmodule\Model\Carrier\Customship1</model>
                <active>0</active>
                <title>customship1</title>
                <name>customship1</name>
                <price>0.00</price>
                <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
            </customship1>
            <customship2>
                <model>Yourvendor\Yourmodule\Model\Carrier\Customship2</model>
                <active>0</active>
                <title>customship2</title>
                <name>customship2</name>
                <price>0.00</price>
                <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
            </customship2>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

After you should create tow two differant shipping methods model file.

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Yourvendor\Yourmodule\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;

class Customship1 extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{

    protected $_code = 'customship1';

    protected $_isFixed = true;

    protected $_rateResultFactory;

    protected $_rateMethodFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');

        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

        if ($shippingPrice !== false) {
            $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod($this->_code);
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true) {
                $shippingPrice = '0.00';
            }

            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

            $result->append($method);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * getAllowedMethods
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return [$this->_code => $this->getConfigData('name')];
    }
}
```

and Customship2 model class

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Yourvendor\Yourmodule\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;

class Customship2 extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{

    protected $_code = 'customship2';

    protected $_isFixed = true;

    protected $_rateResultFactory;

    protected $_rateMethodFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');

        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

        if ($shippingPrice !== false) {
            $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod($this->_code);
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true) {
                $shippingPrice = '0.00';
            }

            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

            $result->append($method);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * getAllowedMethods
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return [$this->_code => $this->getConfigData('name')];
    }
}
```